# How to get this button to reset the timer in this react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, es6-class

I have the following basic ReactJS setup with ES6. When I hit the reset button, the Timer does not go back to "0".  What am I doing wrong? I'm pretty new to React so any code organization and other tips appreciated as well.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      seconds: 0
    }
    this.resetTimer.bind(this)
  }
  resetTimer = () => {
    this.setState({seconds: 0})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <Button label="Start"/>
        <Button label="Stop"/>
        <Button label="Reset" onClick={this.resetTimer} />
        <Timer seconds={this.state.seconds} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onClick} >{this.props.label}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Timer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      seconds: this.props.seconds
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerId = setInterval(
      () => this.tick(),
      1000
    );
  }
  tick() {
    this.setState({ seconds: this.state.seconds + 1});
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerId);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>{secToMin(this.state.seconds)}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your code is that you only assign `seconds` prop value to the `state` in your constructor. The constructor gets called only one time and after that, your changes to `seconds` prop doesn't update the state of the Timer component.

So you need to manually update the state when props get changed. You can use [`componentWillReceiveProps()`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) life cycle method to do that as follows.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  this.state = {
    seconds: nextProps.seconds
  };
}
```

Also, you don't actually need to bind `this` to `resetTimer`, as `resetTimer` is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this). So you can safely remove the `this.resetTimer.bind(this)` line from your constructor.

Comment: thanks, it's still not resetting though even after making your corrections.

Comment: Well, to understand your problem, can I see your Timer component?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for you to properly bind `this` to `resetTimer`;

The first option is for you to do this in your constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    seconds: 0
  }
  this.resetTimer = this.resetTimer.bind(this)
}
```

and set your button like this `<Button label="Reset" onClick={this.resetTimer} />`

The second method is to not include this.resetTimer in your constructor at all, and on your button do this `<Button label="Reset" onClick={this.resetTimer.bind(this)} />`

There are two ways for you to properly bind `this` to `resetTimer`;

The first option is for you to do this in your constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    seconds: 0
  }
  this.resetTimer = this.resetTimer.bind(this)
}
```

and set your button like this `<Button label="Reset" onClick={this.resetTimer} />`

The second method is to not include this.resetTimer in your constructor at all, and on your button do this `<Button label="Reset" onClick={this.resetTimer.bind(this)} />`

You've got a second issue though. Your button component probably doesn't work because your props aren't being set.

In your Button constructor do this:

```
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
 }
```

Or change your button to a stateless component and write it like this:

```
function Button({onClick, label}) {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={onClick} >{label}</button>
      </div>
    );
}
```

A third possible issue could be with your resetTimer function.

```
  resetTimer() {
    this.setState({seconds: 0})
  }
```

try writing it like the above and see if that works.